# Preventing apps from detecting other apps

Tags: applications, installation, permissions

I have an app that does not allow me to enable certain settings because another app is installed. Every time I try to enable these settings it says "You cannot because app x is installed". I know they are both compatible but it has to do with buying certain features from the first app that are free in the second.

Is there a way to prevent the first app from detecting the second app is installed?

Device: Nexus 4
OS/Build: 4.4.4/KTU84P
MODs: Xposed
Rooted: yes (obviously)

Comment: Is it okay to know what are those 2 apps? Without this info, it's hard to analyze if it's possible to prevent detecting other app or not.

Comment: At this stage no :/ i am sorry,  but a general method would do the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive searching found an Xposed module for it! 
xPrivacy!

**EDIT:**

xPrivacy (http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) is an Xposed module that allows you to control what data apps can access (it's more powerful than app-ops or ReceiverStop but more complex).

so what i did:
after installing xPrivacy

1. Scrolled in the app list to find the blocking app
2. Pressed on the picture
3. Scrolled in the restrictions list to "system"
4. pressed on the arrow on the left to expand
5. disabled relevant restrictions (serv_getInstalledApps,serv_getPackageInfo etc..)
6. Had Fun :)

Hope this helps
will be more than happy to add more info if needed :)

Comment: The answer could be a bit more useful if you explained how to get it, what it does and how it helped you.

Comment: Alright will do :)